# How to wait for a period of time or function call, whichever takes longest even when the system time changes?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a situation where I don't want to be executing a particular function *too* quickly.  I currently have this code:

```
DoSomething();
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
```

How can I change this code to run for the max of the function time or the wait time?

**Please note:** I can't use the system time because my software can change the clock time.

So, if `DoSomething()` takes 400 MS, it would only wait 400 MS, but if it took 100 MS, the program would wait 200 MS.

Comment: I apologize for not making the question clear.  I need to do this without relying on the system time.

Comment: You made that quite clear in the first place, no need to apologize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.Start();
DoSomething();
stopWatch.Stop();
var diff = 200 - stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
if(diff > 0)
    Thread.Sleep(diff);
```

The [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class is not using the system clock for its measurement:

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time.

Update:
You write:

> So, if DoSomething() takes 400 MS, it would only wait 400 MS, but if it took 100 MS, the program would wait 200 MS.

I first thought, this was not what you wanted, because, in the second case, it takes a total time of 300 MS. But if that indeed is, what you want, take this code:

```
var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.Start();
DoSomething();
stopWatch.Stop();
var timeToSleep = 200;
if(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < timeToSleep)
    Thread.Sleep(timeToSleep);
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing the correct behavior when looking at your code.  When I changed the time in DoSomething() and also waited 300 MS, it slept when it shouldn't have.

Comment: You wrote: "So, if DoSomething() takes 400 MS, it would only wait 400 MS, but if it took 100 MS, the program would wait 200 MS.". In the second case, this means, it takes a total time of 300 MS. Is that what you want? If so, take my second code sample (I will update my answer)

Answer (score 5):

IF can use the V4 of .Net, create two tasks and wait for both ended.

Something like this :

```
 Task.WaitAll(
     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoSomething()),
     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Thread.Sleep(200))
     );
```

Comment: Nice, almost the same solution I proposed, but much shorter.

Comment: I'm doubting... does using the TPL guaranties to be executed in parallel ? I'm a bit afraid that in some cases under heavy load or on single core computers, the two tasks will run sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

You could time the duration of `DoSomething` with a `Stopwatch` and wait the difference between your target time and the duration of the method call or nothing if the method call exceeds your wait time.

Answer (score 2):

You could make two threads, one that does the actual work, and a second thread that sleeps for a given time. Then you use `Thread.Join()` in the main thread to wait for the two threads to end.

```
// Define the threads and there startpoint
Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoSomething);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));

// Start both threads
thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();

// Wait for both threads to be finished.
thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
```