# What is the best way to implement a Retry Wrapper in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

We currently have a naive RetryWrapper which retries a given func upon the occurrence of an exception:

```
public T Repeat<T, TException>(Func<T> work, TimeSpan retryInterval, int maxExecutionCount = 3) where TException : Exception
{ 
   ...
```

And for the retryInterval we are using the below logic to "wait" before the next attempt.

```
_stopwatch.Start();
while (_stopwatch.Elapsed <= retryInterval)
{
  // do nothing but actuallky it does! lots of CPU usage specially if retryInterval is high
}
_stopwatch.Reset();
```

I don't particularly like this logic, also ideally I would prefer the retry logic NOT to happen on the main thread, can you think of a better way?

Note: I am happy to consider answers for .Net >= 3.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a period of time or function call, whichever takes longest even when the system time changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107522/how-to-wait-for-a-period-of-time-or-function-call-whichever-takes-longest-even)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as your method signature returns a T, the main thread will have to block until all retries are completed. However, you can reduce CPU by having the thread sleep instead of doing a manual reset event:

```
Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
```

If you are willing to change your API, you can make it so that you don't block the main thread. For example, you could use an async method:

```
public async Task<T> RepeatAsync<T, TException>(Func<T> work, TimeSpan retryInterval, int maxExecutionCount = 3) where TException : Exception
{
     for (var i = 0; i < maxExecutionCount; ++i)
     {
        try { return work(); }
        catch (TException ex)
        {
            // allow the program to continue in this case
        }
        // this will use a system timer under the hood, so no thread is consumed while
        // waiting
        await Task.Delay(retryInterval);
     }
}
```

This can be consumed synchronously with:

```
RepeatAsync<T, TException>(work, retryInterval).Result;
```

However, you can also start the task and then wait for it later:

```
var task = RepeatAsync<T, TException>(work, retryInterval);

// do other work here

// later, if you need the result, just do
var result = task.Result;
// or, if the current method is async:
var result = await task;

// alternatively, you could just schedule some code to run asynchronously
// when the task finishes:
task.ContinueWith(t => {
    if (t.IsFaulted) { /* log t.Exception */ }
    else { /* success case */ }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

> The Microsoft Enterprise Library Transient Fault Handling Application
>   Block lets developers make their applications more resilient by adding
>   robust transient fault handling logic. Transient faults are errors
>   that occur because of some temporary condition such as network
>   connectivity issues or service unavailability. Typically, if you retry
>   the operation that resulted in a transient error a short time later,
>   you find that the error has disappeared.

It is available as a NuGet package.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling;
...
// Define your retry strategy: retry 5 times, starting 1 second apart
// and adding 2 seconds to the interval each retry.
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

// Define your retry policy using the retry strategy and the Windows Azure storage
// transient fault detection strategy.
var retryPolicy =
  new RetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

// Receive notifications about retries.
retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Log details of the retry.
        var msg = String.Format("Retry - Count:{0}, Delay:{1}, Exception:{2}",
            args.CurrentRetryCount, args.Delay, args.LastException);
        Trace.WriteLine(msg, "Information");
    };

try
{
  // Do some work that may result in a transient fault.
  retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(
    () =>
    {
        // Your method goes here!
    });
}
catch (Exception)
{
  // All the retries failed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a timer instead of stopwatch?

For example:

```
    TimeSpan retryInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    DateTime startTime;
    DateTime retryTime;
    Timer checkInterval = new Timer();

    private void waitMethod()
    {
        checkInterval.Interval = 1000;
        checkInterval.Tick += checkInterval_Tick;         
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        retryTime = startTime + retryInterval;
        checkInterval.Start();
    }

    void checkInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now >= retryTime)
        {
            checkInterval.Stop();

            // Retry Interval Elapsed
        }   
    }
```

Comment: This is still a spin-wait, and will consume lots of CPU while blocking the main thread. Also, since you keep reassigning startTime this will run forever.

Comment: obviously it needs to be in a function, this is just psudo-code

Comment: @Okuma Yes, it is pseudo-code, but even this pseudo-code will run forever, since `startTime <= startTime + retryInterval` is always `true` when the retryInterval is not equal to zero, which is isn't.

Comment: @Maarten You're right I made a mistake. Hopefully my edit is an improvement.